Python: adding a singleton implementation massively slow down the async code execution
Please appreciate the code below is an excerpt of what is in production today, so alteration have been done to introduce the encountered problem.
from aiolimiter import AsyncLimiter
 
class ServiceCrawler:
    def __init__(self, access_token, ratelimit: int = 0) -> None:
        self.base_url = "https://app.myservice.com/api/"
        self.http_client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True, timeout=None, verify=False)
        self.ratelimit = AsyncLimiter(ratelimit, 30)
        self.accesstoken = access_token

    async def async_http_request(
        self, 
        url: str, 
        method: Http_Methods=Http_Methods.GET,
        payload: json = None, 
        data: json = None
    ) -> json:
        
        headers = {}
        if len(self.access_token) > 0:
            headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {self.access_token}'

        try:
            async with self.ratelimit:
                match method:
                    case Http_Methods.GET:
                        ret = await self.http_client.get(url, headers=headers)
                    case Http_Methods.POST:...


test = ServiceCrawler('', 10)
ret = (await test.async_http_request('https://wwww.something.com'))

The class above is a specialised object built to query an internal API, which is meant to work in asynchronous mode.
As it stands, I have my external routines creating a group of coroutines to launch my internal methods and process the data.
Each request creates a new ServiceCrawler object, which I though it would have been good to incapsulate with a Singleton pattern.
Whether doing this with a metaclass, a global variable ... it's a different story.
Upon having used different approaches, I noticed no benefits at all, in fact a massive reduction in execution that I cannot understand.
Say for instance the following implementation using a global variable.
client = None

class ServiceCrawler:
    def __init__(self, access_token, ratelimit: int = 0) -> None:
        self.base_url = "https://app.myservice.com/api/"
        self.ratelimit = AsyncLimiter(ratelimit, 30)
        self.accesstoken = access_token
        
        global client
        if not client:
              self.http_client = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True, timeout=None, verify=False)
              client = self.http_client
        else:
              self.http_client = client


As soon the code gets in place, all of a sudden my routines takes 1/2 minutes before calling each other. And here I'm wondering if this is due to the singleton approach that is not compatible with the Async, or if there is something else I need to identify, but for which right now I don't have any clue.
Thanks for any hints on how to better implement a singleton pattern on an an async object responsible to make API calls.

Being a singleton per se wouldn´t make a difference - but what is this HTTPClient class  you are using? Does it actually work asynchronously? Please fix your example and change it in to a minimal reproducible example showing how the requests are actually being done. Having as a base what you say, it looks like you are using this http client in a blocking way, inside an asyncio loop.

@jsbueno sorry, forget about HTTPClient ... that was a typo I did in attempting to make the example as reproducible as possible. That is httpx.AsyncClient the library instanciated with its async module.
